# Closing java frame on ESC press

Tags: java, swing

I found this code in several forums to close a frame on ESC keypress. But, I am confused reagrding where to put this peice of code

```
KeyStroke escape = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE, 0, false);
Action action = new AbstractAction() {
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    jDesktopPane1.getSelectedFrame().dispose();
   }
};
jDesktopPane1.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT).put(
escape,"escape");
jDesktopPane1.getActionMap().put("escape", action);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Well, you need a reference to the JDesktopPane, so why don't you do it when you create your JDesktopPane?

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you initialize jDesktopPane1, you can put it right after that and it will bind it to it. If there is an `init()` method for your pane, put it in there so that it gets bound.

Answer (score -2):

We must add a key listener to the java component like frame. Or in your case jdesktoppane.
For an example frame's constructor,

```
this.addKeyAdapter(
    new KeyAdapter(){
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
            if(e.getKeyChar()==VK_ESCAPE)
                this.dispose();
        }
});
```

Comment: -1, no you don't need to add a KeyListener to the component. That is one option but it is a poor option that was done before Swing existed. If fact that approach will not work in many cases because KeyEvents are only passed to the component with focus, so you would need to add the KeyListener to every component on the frame. Swing uses Key Bindings which are the preferred approach.